# Quention about the historical definition of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$ax+by = k_1\\cx + dy = k_2$$

If I want to solve for $y$ in the first equation:

$$by = k_1 - ax\implies y = \frac{k_1-ax}{b}$$

Then substitute $y$ in the second equation:

$$cx + d\frac{k_1-ax}{b} = k_2\implies \frac{bcx}{b}+\frac{dk_1-dax}{b} = k_2\implies\\bcx + dk_1 -dax = bk_2\implies x(bc-da) = bk_2-dk_1\implies\\x = \frac{bk_2 - dk_1}{bc-da}$$

The denominator of this fraction should be the first historical definition of the determinant of the matrix, because it **determinates** when a system has a solution or not.

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$$

should be $ad-bc$ but by my solution to the system, it's the negative of it. I know that to verify that the system has a solution, we must find if the determinant is $0$, so the signal has no problem here. But I would like to know why I get a different determinant here.

I need my solution to match the original definition of determinant because I want to express the solutions for $x$ and $y$ as determinant over determinant, like in the cramer's rule for solving systems.

Also, anybody knows how to empirically obtain the general rule for a determinant of a  $n\times n$ system? It seems pretty dark to me, because I can't find anything on google. All proofs of Cramer's rule already use a definition for determinant, but I see the determinant as a consequence of it, because it **determinates** the existence of a solution. This is pretty importante to me, and I would like to know if there's a book that talks about it, because I've never seen one...

Comment: If you look at the inverse matrix, it looks like

$$\begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a\end{pmatrix}$$

Yours is right, you just need to write it as $${dk_1-bk_2\over ad-bc}$$

to match the two up.

Comment: Sorry but I can't let this go.   The word is "determines" not "determinates".

Comment: @TimRaczkowski sorry, english is not my native language, in portuguese "determinates" made more sense to me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is, but [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) was articulated as a way to solve linear equations, and the definition of "determinant" was abstracted from the quantities that appear (as numerator and denominator) in said rule.

Comment: Take the determinant of $\ \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x & 0\\y & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}k_1 & b\\k_2 & d\end{bmatrix}\ $ to put in in pure multiplicative form.